# Combining Clang AST

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, static-analysis, llvm-clang

I'm trying to work on the AST of multiple files at a go using `RecursiveASTVisitor` and found this method `buildASTs` from `ClangTool` that is said to `Create an AST for each file specified in the command line and append them to ASTs`.

However, I am unable to find examples of use or guides.

Anyone has experience with combining ASTs from multiple source?

What I've done now is this

```
ClangTool Tool(OptionsParser.getCompilations(), OptionsParser.getSourcePathList());
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<clang::ASTUnit>> AST;
Tool.buildASTs(AST);
```

But I don't know how to proceed with the analysis from here..

Comment: Where you able to find how to do this? Even I am running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to combine ASTs, you can merge parts of an AST into another one using clang::ASTImporter.

However the most common strategy is to analyze each AST independently and then merge the results together.

Comment: Is it correct to use `std::vector` to combine them as well?